# What's the equivalent of SHGetFolderPath on OSX?

Tags: c, objective-c, macos

I am porting a Windows application to OSX and need to get user's home, documents and music directories. It is done on Windows using a [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx) WinAPI call.

1. How can I do it in OSX, preferably without resorting to Objective C?
2. If I can't do it without Objective C, how can I do it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` or `FSFindFolder`.

Comment: NSMusicDirectory finally appeared in v10.6.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a user's own home directory by looking at the environment variable `HOME` (for example, "`echo $HOME`" from a shell or `getenv` from C). For the home directory of other users, you can use `getpwnam` or `getpwuid` (see their manpages for more details) to retrieve their home directory. For other directories, you can try the Carbon API [FSFindFolder](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Folder_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSFindFolder).

Answer (score 3):

I know you'd prefer to not use Objective-C, but here is an example of how to do it with Objective-C:

```
static NSString *PathForUserDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory directory) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ([paths count] > 0) {
        return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
NSLog(@"Library folder: %@", PathForUserDirectory(NSLibraryDirectory));
```

which will print the full POSIX path of the current user's library directory. Here is a reference for other directories you can search for:

[NSSearchPathDirectory](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSSearchPathDirectory)